# Python: tkinter / ctkinter - values not populating from entries

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get values and create a Student object, but the values are not populating.

Here is my Student class:

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, firstName=None, lastName=None, dateOfBirth=None, age=None, schoolName=None, schoolId=None, addressLine=None, city=None, zip=None, language=None):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
        self.age = age
        self.schoolName = schoolName
        self.schoolId = schoolId
        self.addressLine = addressLine
        self.city = city
        self.zip = zip
        self.language = language
```

My Main GUI Frame/application that is to gather student details to create a record. Once the details are entered I want to create an instance of a student using the class and save the data (have not gotten to saving the data part as I cant get the data to print).

```
import sys
import tkinter
import customtkinter as ctk
import self
from tkcalendar import *
from datetime import date, datetime
from Student import *

# Theme set-up
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

# GUI set-up
mainMenu = ctk.CTk()
mainMenu.title("GUI Application")
mainMenu.geometry("800x500")

# Frame set-up
mainMenuFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=mainMenu)
mainMenuFrame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

ageSelection = tkinter.StringVar()

#Functions
def exitProgram():
    sys.exit()

def getAge(today, dob, student):
    print(today)
    print(dob)
    dob_result = str(dob)
    dob_data = dob_result.split("-")
    year = int(dob_data[0])
    month = int(dob_data[1])
    day = int(dob_data[2])

    print(year)
    print(month)
    print(day)

    age = (today - date(year, month, day)).days
    age = age / 365
    print(age)
    age = round(age)
    ageSelection = round(age)
    print(round(age))

def createStudentRecord(firstName, lastName, dob, schoolName, schoolId, addressLine, city, zip, language):
    s1 = Student(firstName, lastName,dob,schoolName,schoolId,addressLine, city, zip, language)
    print(firstName)
    print(lastName)
    print(dob)
    print(schoolId)
    print(addressLine)
    print(city)
    print(zip)
    print(language)

def loadStudentInfoView():
    # Remove main menu frame
    mainMenuFrame.pack_forget()

    studentInfoFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=mainMenu)
    studentInfoFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # Student Info set-up

    #First & Last Name
    firstNameLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="First Name", font=('Calibri',20))
    firstNameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

    firstNameText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=150)
    firstNameText.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20)
    firstName = str(firstNameText.get())

    lastNameLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="Last Name", font=('Calibri', 20))
    lastNameLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

    lastNameText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=150)
    lastNameText.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20)

    # Birth date (Calendar), automatically calculate age
    #DOB drop down

    dobLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="DOB", font=('Calibri', 20))
    dobLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)

    calPicker = DateEntry(studentInfoFrame, selectmode="day", year=2014, month=2, day=7, date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
    calPicker.grid(row=1, column=2)

    #School Details
    schoolNameLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="School Name", font=('Calibri', 20))
    schoolNameLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

    schoolNameText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=150)
    schoolNameText.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20)

    #School ID
    schoolIdLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="School ID", font=('Calibri', 20))
    schoolIdLabel.grid(row=2, column=1)

    schoolIdText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=70)
    schoolIdText.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20)

    #Address Line 1 & 2, City, State, Zip
    addressLineLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="Address Line", font=('Calibri', 20))
    addressLineLabel.grid(row=5, column=0)

    addressLineText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=300)
    addressLineText.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20)

    cityLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="City", font=('Calibri', 20))
    cityLabel.grid(row=5, column=1)

    cityText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=120)
    cityText.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=20)

    stateLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="State (dropdown)", font=('Calibri', 20))
    stateLabel.grid(row=5, column=2)

    stateText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=50)
    stateText.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=20)

    zipLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="Zip Code", font=('Calibri', 20))
    zipLabel.grid(row=5, column=3)

    zipText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=50)
    zipText.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=20)

    #Language

    # Create Record Button
    createRecordButton = ctk.CTkButton(master=studentInfoFrame, text="Create Student Record", command=lambda : createStudentRecord(firstName, lastNameText, calPicker, schoolNameText,
                                                                                                                          schoolIdText, addressLineText, cityText, zipText, language=None))
    createRecordButton.grid(row=8, column=1, pady=80)

# Main Menu Layout

# Title Label
title = ctk.CTkLabel(master = mainMenuFrame, text="LSSP Helper", font=('Arial', 32))
title.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Text Label
title2 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Can you")
title2.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Text Label
title3 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = mainMenuFrame, text="please")
title3.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Text Label
title4 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = mainMenuFrame, text="HELLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLP!?!?!?!?!")
title4.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Button 1
button1 = ctk.CTkButton(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Create New Student Record", command=loadStudentInfoView)
button1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Button 2
button2 = ctk.CTkButton(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Resume Student Record")
button2.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Button 3
button3 = ctk.CTkButton(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Observation Form")
button3.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Exit Button
exitButton = ctk.CTkButton(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Exit", command=exitProgram)
exitButton.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

mainMenu.mainloop()
```

Output from function, createStudentRecord, comes out as ctk data??? :

```
# empty value as I tried to use text.get() method
.!ctkframe2.!ctkentry2
.!ctkframe2.!dateentry
.!ctkframe2.!ctkentry4
.!ctkframe2.!ctkentry5
.!ctkframe2.!ctkentry6
.!ctkframe2.!ctkentry8
None
```

Comment: `createStudentRecord()` is receiving the Entries themselves as parameters.  You have to call `.get()` on an Entry to retrieve the text that it holds.

Comment: I thought so too and did that for the firstName and did it before calling the function: firstName = str(firstNameText.get())

Now I tried it and it worked
createStudentRecord(firstNameText.get())

Answer (score 0):

### Description:

The issue you are facing is very easy to solve it just needs a little focus.
So you see after every label you are creating a new variable and storing the value of the entry init.
The issue is that, that variable is storing the value before the button is pressed or in other words as soon as you click the `Create New Student Record` button its storing the value init, since the entry is empty when you open the frame its returning none.

### Solution:

In order to get the values after the user has entered the text use the `.get()` function when the button is pressed after the user is done entering his\her data in the entries. You can use the following fixed code:

```
import sys
import tkinter
import customtkinter as ctk
import self
from tkcalendar import *
from datetime import date, datetime
from Student import *

# Theme set-up
ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

# GUI set-up
mainMenu = ctk.CTk()
mainMenu.title("GUI Application")
mainMenu.geometry("800x500")

# Frame set-up
mainMenuFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=mainMenu)
mainMenuFrame.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

ageSelection = tkinter.StringVar()

#Functions
def exitProgram():
    sys.exit()

def getAge(today, dob, student):
    print(today)
    print(dob)
    dob_result = str(dob)
    dob_data = dob_result.split("-")
    year = int(dob_data[0])
    month = int(dob_data[1])
    day = int(dob_data[2])

    print(year)
    print(month)
    print(day)

    age = (today - date(year, month, day)).days
    age = age / 365
    print(age)
    age = round(age)
    ageSelection = round(age)
    print(round(age))

def createStudentRecord(firstName, lastName, dob, schoolName, schoolId, addressLine, city, zip, language):
    s1 = Student(firstName, lastName,dob,schoolName,schoolId,addressLine, city, zip, language)
    print(firstName)
    print(lastName)
    print(dob)
    print(schoolId)
    print(addressLine)
    print(city)
    print(zip)
    print(language)

def loadStudentInfoView():
    # Remove main menu frame
    mainMenuFrame.pack_forget()

    studentInfoFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(master=mainMenu)
    studentInfoFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

    # Student Info set-up

    #First & Last Name
    firstNameLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="First Name", font=('Calibri',20))
    firstNameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

    firstNameText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=150)
    firstNameText.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20)

    lastNameLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="Last Name", font=('Calibri', 20))
    lastNameLabel.grid(row=0, column=1)

    lastNameText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=150)
    lastNameText.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20)

    # Birth date (Calendar), automatically calculate age
    #DOB drop down

    dobLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="DOB", font=('Calibri', 20))
    dobLabel.grid(row=0, column=2)

    calPicker = DateEntry(studentInfoFrame, selectmode="day", year=2014, month=2, day=7, date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
    calPicker.grid(row=1, column=2)

    #School Details
    schoolNameLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="School Name", font=('Calibri', 20))
    schoolNameLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)

    schoolNameText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=150)
    schoolNameText.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20)

    #School ID
    schoolIdLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="School ID", font=('Calibri', 20))
    schoolIdLabel.grid(row=2, column=1)

    schoolIdText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=70)
    schoolIdText.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20)

    #Address Line 1 & 2, City, State, Zip
    addressLineLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="Address Line", font=('Calibri', 20))
    addressLineLabel.grid(row=5, column=0)

    addressLineText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=300)
    addressLineText.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20)

    cityLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="City", font=('Calibri', 20))
    cityLabel.grid(row=5, column=1)

    cityText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=120)
    cityText.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=20)

    stateLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="State (dropdown)", font=('Calibri', 20))
    stateLabel.grid(row=5, column=2)

    stateText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=50)
    stateText.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=20)

    zipLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(master=studentInfoFrame, text="Zip Code", font=('Calibri', 20))
    zipLabel.grid(row=5, column=3)

    zipText = ctk.CTkEntry(master=studentInfoFrame, height=30, width=50)
    zipText.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=20)

    #Language


    # Create Record Button
    createRecordButton = ctk.CTkButton(master=studentInfoFrame, text="Create Student Record", command=lambda : createStudentRecord(firstNameText.get(), lastNameText.get(), calPicker.get_date(), schoolNameText.get(),
                                                                                                                          schoolIdText.get(), addressLineText.get(), cityText.get(), zipText.get(), language=None))
    createRecordButton.grid(row=8, column=1, pady=80)

# Main Menu Layout

# Title Label
title = ctk.CTkLabel(master = mainMenuFrame, text="LSSP Helper", font=('Arial', 32))
title.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Text Label
title2 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Can you")
title2.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Text Label
title3 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = mainMenuFrame, text="please")
title3.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Text Label
title4 = ctk.CTkLabel(master = mainMenuFrame, text="HELLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLP!?!?!?!?!")
title4.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Button 1
button1 = ctk.CTkButton(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Create New Student Record", command=loadStudentInfoView)
button1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Button 2
button2 = ctk.CTkButton(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Resume Student Record")
button2.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Button 3
button3 = ctk.CTkButton(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Observation Form")
button3.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

# Exit Button
exitButton = ctk.CTkButton(master = mainMenuFrame, text="Exit", command=exitProgram)
exitButton.pack(pady=12, padx=10)

mainMenu.mainloop()
```